# Is Xanthophyll good at absorbing Light? or do i need another light wavelenght?

Tags: flora, light, colors

I want my alien planet to have yellow or orange-yellow plants.

Is xanthophyll a good option for plants to absorb light, or do I need to make my sun give off More of a certain wavelength so they can be yellow?

Or blue, if they need to block harmful light (if I'm correct).

Basically, can I use a yellow pigment Like xanthophyll (or others) to absorb light instead of chlorophyll for alien plants to successfully live. Or do I need to change the amount of a certain wavelength sent to them by the sun.

Comment: To help narrow your question, the color of the star is unlikely to affect plant life as much as you might think and by itself (or possibly not at all) won't affect the color of your plants. Plants grab the blue spectrum because of its high energy content, not its color, and all stars emit something in the blue spectrum.

Comment: (1) On out own Earth photosynthetic life can be [red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_algae), [brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_algae), green, [blue-green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanobacteria) or [blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaucophyte), and even (rarely) yellow (as in the case of *Acer palmatum* "Golden Pond"). Land plants are green because they are descended from green algae and not because of the spectrum of solar light. (2) No plant uses chlorophyll alone; [light-harvesting complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-harvesting_complex) are, well, complex.

Answer (score 1):

### Well, sort of.

Xanthophyll itself is not capable of photosynthesis. It is involved in [non-photochemical quenching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-photochemical_quenching), an essential biological process that only *regulates* photosynthesis, by helping turn excess light into heat.

This doesn't mean you can't have yellow plants, though; chlorophyll reflects yellow-green light, and putting a high concentration of xanthophyll into the leaves will absorb the green light, leaving a yellow color. This will somewhat reduce photosynthetic efficacy by preventing the chlorophyll from converting as much light as it can while also generating more heat in the plants. If your alien plants live in colder climates with high light intensities, this may be useful.

#### What about the wavelength of the star?

All this is assuming that the spectrum of light is similar to ordinary sunlight. As the plants use chlorophyll, no changes in *spectrum* are necessary to help the plants survive. However, making the star brighter and the climate colder would make the color more advantageous to the plants.

Of course, you could just take regular earth-plants and alter the star to produce more yellow and less green, but that wouldn't really be changing the color of the plants, and would just make *everything* look more yellow.